# One aux to 6 RCA inputs

Tags: surround-sound, rca

I bought an old surround system which has 6 RCA cable inputs (1 for each of the 5 speakers and one for the sub). 
each input is directed to a single speaker.
because I have only a single aux to 2 RCA cable I can only use it as stereo.

anybody knows how can i split my aux cable to 6 rca's?

I've tried to find the right program and some more inputs. but it seemes the a cable\adaptor\switch solution is needed...

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have a stereo source, you will not be able to use this system as a true surround sound with your current output. You can get quadraphonic + 1 by using adapters such as these:
[image: spliccter]
But be aware you will need a ton of them! It will also look very messy and the signal won't be very good because you have split it so many times. They do make "Active" splitters that will boost the signal, but they can be pricy and you still will not get true surround sound. You best bet would be to buy a sound card that has the outputs as 3.5mm jacks, use adapters to change to RCA cables, and plug those cables into your amplifier. This will give you true surround sound.
[image]

Comment: an extrnal voice card will also work?

Comment: something like this: http://www.amazon.com/Encore-Electronics-ENMAB-8CM-7-1-Channel-Audio/dp/B004VCM4J8

Comment: It looks like that could work, though I have no experience with that particular unit.